# How is a regular surface in $\Bbb{R}^{3}$ different from an ordinary surface?

Tags: differential-geometry

I have two books by Manfredo Do Carmo. He uses the concept of a regular surface in both books. In case you haven't read his definition, here it is:

> A subset $S \subset \Bbb{R}^{3}$ is a regular surface if, for every point $p \in S$, there exists a neighborhood $V$ of $p$ in $\Bbb{R}^{3}$ and a mapping $\mathbf{x}: U \subset \Bbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow V \cap S$ of an open subset $U \subset \Bbb{R}^{2}$ onto $V \cap S$, such that:
>
> 1. $\mathbf{x}$ is a differentiable homeomorphism
> 2. The differential $(d\mathbf{x})_q: \Bbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \Bbb{R}^{3}$ is injective for all $q \in U$

For some people, this definition may make perfectly obvious how a regular surface is different from an ordinary surface. But for me, I don't get the difference.

**Can someone explain? Perhaps using an example would help.**

Comment: What is  an "ordinary surface" in the context of this question?

Comment: I just meant like a surface in $\Bbb{R}^{3}$. Like the kind you use in the most basic forms of math. Like a sphere for instance is a surface in $\Bbb{R}^{3}$.

Comment: No difference. A surface (unless you allow singularities — like a cone — or corners — like a cube) is a $2$-dimensional manifold, and that's what doCarmo's regular surface is.

Comment: But then why does he go through such effort to point out these properties?

Comment: Because we have to use the definition to do differential geometry. When you learn a standard multivariable calculus course, everything is sloppy and engineering-style :P